# When flagging a question, the previous modal window appears when flag the question or close the current window

Tags: bug, design, flag-dialog

When flagging a question, the previous modal window (**I am flagging to report this question as**) appears again when we click the "Flag Question" or close the current window.

[image]

I can reproduce this issue, when ever I'm using the slow internet connection. If the internet speed is high, I can't get enough time to see the extra window.

Comment: Yup, can confirm it appears for a split of a second even with fast connection. Not fatal, but doesn't look good.